# Is it possible to initialize a property of an attribute class by where it's marked?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, attributes

I have an attribute to mark enum fields named BusinessDescription.

```
public enum FailReason
{
   [BusinessDescription(Description="the client cancelled the order")]
   Client = 0,
   [BusinessDescription(Description="vender cancelled", DBValue = 1)]
   Vender = 1,
   [BusinessDescription(Description="other")]
   Other = 2
}
```

You see, the attributes of Client & Other don't contain DBValue values. Is it possible that: if other developers didn't give a DBValue, the constructor will assign corresponding value to it? (for Client, DBValue will be 0; for Other, DBValue will be 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The purpose of an `Attribute` is to provide information about the target that it's been applied to, there's no built-in functionality to allow an attribute to detect its target or any data related to it. From what i see `DBValue` is equal to the value stored in each of the enum's members and you can easily use that value and remove the `DBValue` parameter from the constructor.

Comment: OK. I would think that it's impossible either. Just asked on SO to try if there is a miracle.